# How much should batch size and number of epochs be when fitting a model in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am training a model with 107850 samples and validating on 26963 samples.

How much should batch size and number of epochs be when fitting a model in Keras to optimize the validation accuracy? Is there any sort of rule of thumb to use based on data input size? Does it overfit a model if an increased number of epochs?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

No! Their is not any rule of thumb for selecting the batch size of the data. Its a trade off between better accuracy and time. So we have to take the batch size which will process our data fast and give good accuracy too. Now what happens when you take too large batch size. Actually after every batch your model is going to update their all the weights. Large batch size large error than according to the error your model will adjust weight. Now After processing a large number of batch and update the weight take less time than taking smaller batch and updating the weights after every batch. But when you take small batch size your model will update weights after every batch **i.e(16,32,64)** etc whatever you want than your model will be able to learn your data more accurately but its take time to update all the weights after every batch.

**Now According to the research papers most of the researchers use batch size
(16,32,64) may be researcher use larger batch sizes but I haven't seen yet.
I hope that answer is helpful for you.**

and if you want number of epochs to be optimized use callbacks for your neural network your neural network will automatically stop learning if your model is not learning for more than 4 or 5 epochs depends on you.